# Solution of a differential equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=c_1 +c_2\frac{1}{g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

Throughout my study and research, I currently know the solution to the equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=c$ is $f(x) = f(0) + cx$, where $c$ is a constant. 
Also, I learned from here that solution to the equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=c\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ is $f(x)=cg(x)+C$. Is $C=f(0)-cg(0)$ correct? But I'm still fuzzy about how to obtain $C$. It can be anything, right? Can the value of $C$ be obtained if only I'm given with what $f(0)$ is?

But my main struggle is finding solution to: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=c_1+c_2\frac{1}{g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$

or simply:
$$f'=c_1+c_2\frac{g'}{g}$$

I ultimately want to find the following integral:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

in terms of $g$, $a$, $b$, $c_1$, $c_2$ and probably another constant $C$ . Thanks.

Comment: $$f' = c_{1} + c_{2} \frac{g'}{g} \implies f = c_{1} x + c_{2} \ln g + c_{3}$$

Now apply your limits.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks. Can you comment on the first part of my questions that I'm fuzzy about. I mean the value of C. Since it's not open a new question for me that, what is $c_3$? Is it simply $f(0)-c_1 x - c_2 lng(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=c_1 +c_2\frac{1}{g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$
Integration is straightforward :

$$f(x)=c_1x+c_2\ln\big|g(x) \big|+c_3$$

$c_3$ is an arbitrary constant if no initial condition is specified.

If you want to find the integral: $\quad \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}\left(c_1x+ c_2\ln\big|g(x)\big|+c_3\right)dx$

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx= \frac{1}{2}c_1(b^2-a^2)+c_3(b-a)+c_2\int_{a}^{b} \ln\big|g(x)\big| dx $$

The definite integral $\quad \int_{a}^{b} \ln\big|g(x)\big| dx \quad$ cannot be expressed on a simpler form if $g(x)$ is not explicitly known.

At this state, $c_3$ isn't defined (it is an arbitrary constant).

If the values of $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ are known, $c_3$ becomes defined :
$$f(0)=c_2\ln\big|g(0) \big|+c_3 \quad\to\quad c_3=f(0)-c_2\ln\big|g(0) \big|$$
It is similar if the values of $f$ and $g$ are known at another abscissa than $0$, for example at $x=a$. Compute $c_3$ on the same manner.

Then, you can put it into the above formula.